# Is stack migration a standard attack technique?

Tags: exploit, stack

I am reading up a writeup on an example attack [here](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lxpark.com%2Fctf%2Fpwnable-kr-unlink-writeup&edit-text=&act=url) where I have come across the technique called `stack migration`. The page is translated to English. Googling doesn't give me any fruitful pointer on the technique itself. Is `stack migration` a standard attack technique? If so, pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Chinese but It seems the post describes *stack pivoting*. It is a technique used in cases where you can't control the contents of the actual stack used by the target but can change the stack pointer to point into some other memory area you control (e.g. heap). For example, [this blog post](http://hypervsir.blogspot.com/2015/01/a-software-solution-to-defend-against.html) explains:

> With stack pivoting, attacks can pivot from the real stack to a fake
> stack which could be an attacker-controlled buffer, such as the heap,
> then attackers can control the program execution. For example, this is
> achieved by controlling data pointed to by RSP(stack pointer
> register), such that each ret instruction results in incrementing RSP
> and transferring execution to the next address chosen by attackers.

So yes, it's a real and common technique, you just used not the best translation :)